# Reducing master row height to less than 42px when having detail row in ag grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I know that by using getRowHeight we can reduce height of rows in detail of master grid. I want to reduce the rowHeight of master grid. Does anyone know how can we do that ?

Find the below image if this helps

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution of above statement.
Please add your other details in gridOptions along with the details i added below.

```
var currentRowHeight = 22;
var gridOptions = {
     onGridReady: function(params) {
         currentRowHeight = 22;
     },
     onGridSizeChanged: onGridSizeChanged,
     getRowHeight: function() {
         return currentRowHeight;
     }
}
function onGridSizeChanged() {
    params.api.resetRowHeights()
}
```

This will make your master grid row height reduced to 22px;
One more change you might need to do is tochange the css of ag-group-value to make the arrow appear in same line.